# Netbeans 7.3 Error in Startup

Tags: netbeans

After I upgraded from Netbeans 7.2 to 7.3  I get the below error. I tried uninstalling Netbeans including setting files etc. and reinstalled it .. But the error persists.

> Warning - could not install some modules: org.eclipse.equinox.common -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans
>   7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-equinox-common.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.equinox.common state remains INSTALLED after start()
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans
>   7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-core-runtime-compatibility-auth.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth state remains
>   INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.core.jobs -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans
>   7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-core-jobs.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.core.jobs state remains INSTALLED after start()
>   org.eclipse.equinox.registry - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   X:\IDE\NetBeans 7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-equinox-registry.jar:
>   Cannot start org.eclipse.equinox.registry state remains INSTALLED
>   after start() org.eclipse.equinox.app - org.netbeans.InvalidException:
>   Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans 7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-equinox-app.jar:
>   Cannot start org.eclipse.equinox.app state remains INSTALLED after
>   start() org.eclipse.equinox.preferences -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans
>   7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-equinox-preferences.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.equinox.preferences state remains INSTALLED after start()
>   org.eclipse.core.contenttype - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   X:\IDE\NetBeans 7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-core-contenttype.jar:
>   Cannot start org.eclipse.core.contenttype state remains INSTALLED
>   after start() org.eclipse.core.runtime -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans
>   7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-core-runtime.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.core.runtime state remains INSTALLED after start()
>   org.eclipse.equinox.security - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   X:\IDE\NetBeans 7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-equinox-security.jar:
>   Cannot start org.eclipse.equinox.security state remains INSTALLED
>   after start() org.eclipse.core.net - org.netbeans.InvalidException:
>   Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans 7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-core-net.jar:
>   Cannot start org.eclipse.core.net state remains INSTALLED after
>   start() org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans
>   7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-core.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core state remains INSTALLED after start()
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans
>   7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-repositories-core.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core state remains
>   INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans
>   7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-net.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net state remains INSTALLED after start()
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso:
>   X:\IDE\NetBeans 7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-tasks-core.jar:
>   Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core state remains INSTALLED
>   after start() org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans
>   7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-xmlrpc.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc state remains INSTALLED after start()
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException:
>   Netigso: X:\IDE\NetBeans
>   7.3\ide\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-bugzilla-core.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core state remains INSTALLED after start()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to clean your userdir http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

But be careful it will erase all your IDE settings

Comment: you are a f*#$% genius !! ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple :

1 - Try to find this file **/home/yourname/.cache/netbeans**

2 - And clear all files [image]

Answer (score 3):

If cleaning out your userdir doesn't work, try deleting the netbeans cache: rm -rf ~/.cache/netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Rename the modules folder out of within your userdir and then reinstall 7.3.  This works and loses none of your custom settings.

Comment: Calligra, there is more than one modules subfolders within the userdir folder. Could you clarify which modules subfolder by indicating the correct folder path? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you could delete only the file `org.eclipse.equinox.common` in modules directory (and any other modules that were showing errors) and keep all the other modules and settings in place.

Answer (score 0):

in netbeans user dir user \ config \ Modules save a backup of all the files inside, then delete this folder and start netbeans, the folder will be recreated after the close netbeans, then add the files that are not inside the folder modules

Answer (score 0):

For 7.2 version, if none of the other solutions was useful, try the following (settings will be lost):

1. *(Consider to make a copy of the whole Netbeans installed folder for any future possible need)*
2. Uninstall Netbeans IDE.
3. Delete the *userdir* and *cachedir* contents, where *userdir* is located usually at "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\" , and the *cachedir* at "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.2\".
4. Install the IDE again.